# Get crash and log information easily from the user on MacOS

Tags: macos, logging, crash

I'm developing an application on MacOSX (using Qt) and my users starts to use it.

It writes a log to *~/Library/Logs/MyOrganization/MyProgram.log*

I would like to be able to get the log and the crash information from the user in the easiest way possible for him.

Is there a way to handle application crash default dialog from Macos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the killer module to perform what I want to do: https://github.com/tcurdt/feedbackreporter